# Obtaining file basename with a prespecified extension in Python

Tags: python, path, filenames

I have the following string:

```
/path1/path2/foo.bar.qux.txt
```

What I want to do is to extract the basename by specifying the extension. 
If I define the extension to be `.bar.qux.txt` then the base name is "`foo`".
Then if the extension is `.qux.txt` then the base is: `foo.bar`.

Perl has the following function:

```
use File::Basename;
my $longones = "/path1/path2/foo.bar.qux.txt";
my $base = basename($longones,"*.bar.qux.txt");
print "$base\n";
```

What's the Python way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in function that does what you want. [`os.path.splitext`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) doesn't allow to define what should be considered an extension. In fact the name `basename` for the perl function is a misnaming because in *NIX `basename` *does* contain the extension.

However you can combine [`os.path.basename`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) with a [`rsplit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename('/path1/path2/foo.bar.qux.txt').rsplit('.bar.qux.txt')[0]
'foo'
>>> os.path.basename('/path1/path2/foo.bar.qux.txt').rsplit('.qux.txt')[0]
'foo.bar'
```

Note that if the filename contains the extension you might get a wrong result:

```
>>> os.path.basename('/path1/path2/foo.bar.qux.txt.foo.bar.qux.txt').rsplit('.qux.txt')[0]
'foo.bar'
```

However you can always specify a `maxsplit` of `1` to only split the first extension:

```
>>> os.path.basename('/path1/path2/foo.bar.qux.txt.foo.bar.qux.txt').rsplit('.qux.txt', maxsplit=1)[0]
'foo.bar.qux.txt.foo.bar'
```

<sup>In python2 you must specify the second argument positionally as `rsplit(text, 1)`.</sup>

Alternatively use [`rpartition`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition):

```
>>> os.path.basename('/path1/path2/foo.bar.qux.txt.foo.bar.qux.txt').rpartition('.qux.txt')[0]
'foo.bar.qux.txt.foo.bar'
```

A solution with regexes could be:

```
import re

def basename_without_ext(path, ext):
    regex = re.compile('{}$'.format(re.escape(ext)))
    return regex.sub('', os.path.basename(path))
```

Used as:

```
>>> basename_without_ext('/path1/path2/foo.bar.qux.txt.foo.bar.qux.txt', '.qux.txt')
'foo.bar.qux.txt.foo.bar'
>>> basename_without_ext('/path1/path2/foo.bar.qux.txt', '.bar.qux.txt')
'foo'
```

Comment: Thanks a million. One last thing how can I break the first code you gave me into two lines? `os.path.basename('/path1/path2/foo.bar.qux.txt').rsplit('.bar.qux.txt')[0]` is kind a long.

Comment: @pdubois Well, you could put that into a function, or assign the result of the call to `basename` to a temporary variable, like: `base = os.path.basename(...); base.rsplit(extension)[0]`.

Answer (score -1):

Python has `os.path.basename` but it doesn't let you define the extension though:

```
import os
os.path.basename(filename)
```

Using `str.endswith()` and slicing seems easy enough though.